# External app access to SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, app, cross-domain

I am a new user of SharePoint and I am currently developing a SharePoint app.
This app is an externally hosted app, so it is not on the same domain than the farm. In this app, I use the REST API to access to a list stored in the Sharepoint farm but it caused an error.

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

The first time I saw this, I searched how to avoid it. I found on the net I have to make a CORS request. So I tried, but the problem is still the same.

Can you tell me, if it is possible to access to a list from the other domain?
And if not, the other way to dot what I want.

Comment: I found the solution. I just used the SP.RequestExecutor.js script. If you want more informations, look at [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library)